# Dropdown list using Jquery menu list disappear when click on drop down list button after postback

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server

I have strange issue. I am using few editable cascading dropdownlist controls inside updated panel on my asp.net page. These are also using JQuery for autocomplete feature and these dropdowns loading from database. It works ok very first time and user can select facility and click save button and save facility and page data. After saving, user click new button to enter a new entry. When click new button it keeps all the previous values inside dropdown selection. When try to change facility value and click on dropdown button to open the list and select value but list items/menu inside dropdownlist appears and disappears suddenly so that user is unable to select any value. Not sure exactly what causing this. I have checked if there is any memory leak or viewstate causing this but everything seems fine.
Did anyone experience same issue? Any help will be appreciated. Let me know if require additional information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Place Your jQuery code within:

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
    if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) {
        //Here Your   $(document).ready(function () {

   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Amit. 

Actually I am using editable drop down list control which using Jquery library on my page.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/290218/Custom-ASP-NET-Editable-DropDownList


 So my page do not have any Jquery code. 

Dropdown code looks like below

<editable:EditableDropDownList ID="ddlFromFacility" CssClass="ddlParameterComboBoxTicketEditor"    TabIndex="30" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlFromFacility_SelectedIndexChanged"
 AutoselectFirstItem="true">
                            </editable:EditableDropDownList>